# build executable with msg

Tags: ros, build, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a source file using a message belonging to the same package.

In Package A

- bb.cpp
- cc.msg

The problem is that bb.cpp includes the header file of cc.msg - cc.h
when I start to build as 'winros_make'
it looks executables are built before the messages in there.
i think messages should be built first and then executables be.

there are any way to build message first? so executable can access the header file of them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162266/build-executable-with-msg/) by [Younghyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14156/younghyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add a dependency line to your CMakeLists.txt which declares that your executable depends on building messages:

```
add_dependencies(your_program ${your_package_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

For a more detailed explanation, see the [building messages howto](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/building_msgs.html)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Younghyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14156/younghyo/) on 2014-05-12**:
i solved it by adding this.
add_dependencies(bb A_gencpp)
thank you.